# Visual studio 2017 not using libcurl correctly

Tags: c++

Today i tried to install libcurl using the NUget package manager. When i tried to run my piece of code the following error occured:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ProjectName, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>stdafx.cpp
1>ProjectName.cpp
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000109) "extern "C" void __cdecl curl_global_cleanup(void)" (?curl_global_cleanup@@$$J0YAXXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00010A) "extern "C" void __cdecl curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00010D) "extern "C" char const * __cdecl curl_easy_strerror(enum CURLcode)" (?curl_easy_strerror@@$$J0YAPBDW4CURLcode@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000113) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __cdecl curl_easy_perform(void *)" (?curl_easy_perform@@$$J0YA?AW4CURLcode@@PAX@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000114) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __cdecl curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YA?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000115) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __cdecl curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YA?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000116) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __cdecl curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YA?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000117) "extern "C" void * __cdecl curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YAPAXXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000177) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __cdecl curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YA?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" enum CURLcode __cdecl curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YA?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void * __cdecl curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YAPAXXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" enum CURLcode __cdecl curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YA?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" enum CURLcode __cdecl curl_easy_perform(void *)" (?curl_easy_perform@@$$J0YA?AW4CURLcode@@PAX@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" char const * __cdecl curl_easy_strerror(enum CURLcode)" (?curl_easy_strerror@@$$J0YAPBDW4CURLcode@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>ProjectName.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl curl_global_cleanup(void)" (?curl_global_cleanup@@$$J0YAXXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ProjectName\Debug\ProjectName.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 16 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "ProjectName.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Any fix?

Comment: Looks like the library's `*.lib` file is not specified in the linker input. Please be more specific. Show us *how* Visual Studio invokes the compiler and linker.

Comment: sounds stupid but what do you mean.

Comment: Have you ever used a 3rd-party library with Visual C++ before? Or with C++ in general? Including headers is almost always not enough; you also need to link to the library's binary code, which you've either built yourself or downloaded. Otherwise, the compiler compiles everything nicely (because it finds the headers), but when the linker tries to link everything together, it fails to find the implementation of the library's functions - which is exactly what these error messages are saying.

Comment: well actually the libcurl.lib files are missing. as i said in the Q, i've installed libcurl and all dependencies using the NUget package manager.

Comment: I have never used NuGet with Visual Studio, but I suspect it put the header files and one or more *.lib files suitable for your platform and compiler on your hard disk somewhere. You still need to tell the linker to pick up the *.lib files by specifying them at the linker dependencies option.

Comment: so i've found the .lib file in the "packages" folder "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ProjectName\packages\curl.7.30.0.2\build\native\lib\v110\Win32\Debug\ltcg" is this the folder where i link it?

Comment: You must add the path to the Visual Studio "library directories" if it isn't already there. Then in your application project, just add the *name* of the *.lib file (without the complete path) to the linker dependencies.

Comment: Im having the same problem. Have specified the path in "Additional Library Dependancies" and added libcurl.lib to "Additional Dependancies" and still getting the same error